# assign class member's address to method variable for persistent changes

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-assignment

I have a method that I want to run iteratively on one of two data members, alternating between them.  I thought of doing the following

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    Graph G;
    &G = iteration_number%2 ? &A : &B;
    helper_method_which_modifies(G);
    iteration_number++;
    return;
}
```

where `A` and `B` and `iteration_number` are all `myClass` members but I'm not sure it will work.  It seems right to me but the style rubs me wrong.  The desired result is to call `object.alternating_method()` in a loop and have it modify `object.A` and `object.B` .

Will this work?  Is there a better way?  Will it have unexpected consequences?  Do I need to worry about a destructor being called for `G` when it goes out of scope?

EDIT: To clarify, I meant `helper_method_which_modifies` as shorthand for 100 lines containing several methods.  The ones that modify `G` are mostly boost graph methods.  Now that I see the answers, it seems the best thing is to have an `alternator` which does nothing but choose between `A` and `B` and then pass the correct variable off to another method.

Comment: It won't work because `&G` is an rvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated by  Luchian Grigore, it won't work because you need a L-value.

The idea is working though with little changes.

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    Graph& G = iteration_number%2 ? A : B;
    helper_method_which_modifies(G);
    iteration_number++;
    return;
}
```

Or with a bit more changes:

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    helper_method_which_modifies((++iteration_number%2) ? A : B);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `G` be a reference:

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    Graph& G = iteration_number%2 ? A : B;
    helper_method_which_modifies(G);
    iteration_number++;
    return;
}
```

The other alternative is to eliminate G altogether:

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    helper_method_which_modifies(iteration_number%2 ? A : B);
    iteration_number++;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the `&` operator is the address-of operator. However, you can't assign to an address (search for e.g. "rvalue versus lvalue" or similar).

What you can do it declare `G` as a *pointer* and make that pointer point to either `A` or `B`:

```
Graph* G = iteration_number%2 ? &A : &B;
```

The other solution, since you are using C++, is to make `G`  a *reference*:

```
Graph& G = iteration_number%2 ? A : B;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call it without using `G` ? In this way you have no need to worry about it.

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    helper_method_which_modifies((iteration_number%2 ? &A : &B));
    iteration_number++;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no real need for the place holder G.

```
void myClass::alternating_method(){
    if(iteration_number%2 == 1) {
        helper_method_which_modifies(A);
    } else {
        helper_method_which_modifies(B);
    }
    iteration_number++;
}
```